# sort linux command alphabetically leave empty cells to the end

Tags: linux, sorting

Can someone help me how to sort column alphabetically leaving blank cells to the end. I have gone through some examples already posted here which is of numeric sorting. I have big csv file which has many columns. I wanted to sort based on user which is my second column. My first column may have some blank cells which i want to come at the end. I tried below awk command using sort but didn't work. Can some please help me.

awk '$2 ~ /[0-9]$/' d.txt | sort  -k2g && awk '$2 !~ /[0-9]$/' d.txt

My csv file looks like this

[image]

Answer (score 0):

one idea is to

1. set each of the empty cells to 3 consecutive characters of

   - `U+10FFFF ( \364\217\277\277 | F4 8F BF BF )`, the `UTF-8` character with the highest ordinal value,
2. sort it,
3. then delete those characters out later

such a sequence is extremely improbable to exist in typical input, while also being fully valid `UTF-8` code points, thus avoiding the triggering of any warning or error messages from sorting utilities

Comment: Thank you for your answer. problem is the file is very big and there will be many such blank cells. manually modifying will be not possible